# Can i remove segment before file extension in backup log's file name? error-log-2019-10-25.1.log to error-log-2019-10-25.log

Tags: c#, log4net

i want remove segment before extension in my log file name!is there any ways?

my result is error-file.2019-10-25.1.log

but i want error-file.2019-10-25.log   without segment '1';

```
<appender name="FileErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Logs4Net\error-log-%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss}"/>

  <threshold value="Error" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <countDirection value="1"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2000" />
  <maximumFileSize value="25KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: You should elaborate more? Is it the literal digit `1` that you always want to remove? Or is it a single digit number before the extension? Or can that length be different? And what's the relationship to that snippet you've provided?

Comment: You are using the `rollingStyle` of `Size` which means the file has to roll to a new name when it exceeds the size. What new name do you expect it to use when the rollover happens in one day?

Comment: You could set `maxSizeRollBackups` to `0` and have no backup files if the size rollover occurs on the same day - you would just lose logging when you hit `maximumFileSize`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a log file per day by changing the `rollingStyle` property to `Date`.  Below is an example of a rolling file appender by date:

```
<appender name="FileErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Logs4Net\error-log.log"/>

  <threshold value="Error" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <encoding value="utf-8" />

  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="-yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />

  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

This will create a file per day (named `error-log.log`) and uses `preserveLogFileNameExtension`. It will rename the file at the end of the day in the format `error-log-yyyy-MM-dd.log`.

There is no size limit using this setup. If you were to add a file size limit and the log file exceeded that limit in a single day, then it would revert to appending `.1`, `.2` etc to your file names.